# How can I properly write a SQL query to update record data in a JTable?

Tags: java, mysql, sql

To better imagine the situation, I have a `Jtable` - which saves some records. When I want to edit a record - I have a button for this - I click on it, edit the cell. but the data is not saved, after refreshing the program, do not see the edited record, only the previous record.

**query**: `update employe set name = ?,salary = ?,number = ? where id = ?`

I suppose there is something wrong with the query ( not too specific?).
The previous version of the program did not allow to point to a given record with the mouse, but I entered a given record for editing in the text field and the query worked - there I pointed to a specific id for editing, now it points only to a given cell.
And I am wondering what is the problem, after all, the cell is edited but not saved?

```
updateButton.addActionListener(e -> {
            String id, name, salary, mobile;
            name = txtName.getText();
            salary = txtSalary.getText();
            mobile = txtNumber.getText();
            id = txtID.getText();

            try {
                updateSelectedRows(table);// allows to edit cells with the mouse

                pst = con.prepareStatement("update employe set name = ?,salary = ?,number = ? where id = ?");
                pst.setString(1, name);
                pst.setString(2, salary);
                pst.setString(3, mobile);
                pst.setString(4, id);

                pst.executeUpdate();
                tab_show();//refresh table, SELECT database query
                txtName.setText("");
                txtSalary.setText("");
                txtNumber.setText("");
                txtName.requestFocus();
            } catch (SQLException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
```

function `updateSelectedRows`:

```
public void updateSelectedRows(JTable table) {

        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table1.getModel();
        int i = table.getSelectedRow();
        model.setValueAt(txtName.getText(), i, 1);
        model.setValueAt(txtSalary.getText(), i, 2);
        model.setValueAt(txtNumber.getSelectedItem(), i, 3);

    }
```

Comment: So, you need to verify if auto commit is enabled our not, if it's not, then you'll need to commit the changes.  You should also careful ensure that you're closing your resources

Comment: *"I suppose there is something wrong with the query"* Stop guessing and confirm it in a console app. Until such times as you have done that, I am removing the Swing tags. It's basic debugging that should be done before asking a question on SO.